# Calculating location using gyroscope & accelerometer

Tags: android, core-location

I wanted to open this up to other to see if anyone has any ideas about this?
We are creating an app that is using corelocation & a bit of physics.. however we are not getting this accuracy... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTZFRDBdQck&feature=related

Any thoughts on what they have done to make this so accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a map to associate with motion it gets pretty easy to correct trajectory. If you try to draw motion from scratch it's a tad harder as you can't compensate it with any known environment. Plus they say they use a compass only, whose accuracy highly relies on the surrounding magnetic field (as it gets crazy off the grid when disturbances are around).

Comment: Thank you.. Yes we would certainly have the maps of the location.. but still correcting the trajectory and having an accurate change is what we are having issues with.  We can trace a path but that path starts to veer off a bit.. Have you had luck tracking a position accurately  using this method...

Comment: Yeah, I've implemented a Pedestrian Navigation System based on a pedometer for distances and using the gyroscope to update the heading of the walking user. I haven't had the time to apply enough correction to make it really accurate, but that could be achieved. You add maps over this, you can definitively get something impressive.

Comment: any hints or tips you can share about how you did it?  I had another project drop in my lap so I haven't had the time to get back to this... That project is up next!

Comment: Hmmm basically pattern-matching for the step detection (you recognize some patterns on the vertical axis from the accelerometer) and the use of Direction Cosine Matrix or quaternions to store and update the orientation changes. Then you can multiply your motion vector by the rotation matrix (or its inverse) and you can find your motion vector in the Earth-frame. This is basically how I achieved it, ofcourse it gets harder than it looks :p